# How can I ise Page objects

Tags: testing, jvm, cucumber

I'm beginner in cucumber jvm, can anyone explain to me how can I work with page objects?

I don't know how can I organize my project.

Comment: I'd suggest to check the info provided under the [tag:cucumber] tag info.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but http://www.seleniumframework.com/cucumber-jvm-3/cucumber-jvm-and-page-object/.

Answer (score 0):

A page object is an abstraction that simplifies the interaction with a web page when writing a test for the web page. It is one way to [separate concern](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/01/14/separation-of-concern-when-using-selenium).

When you are implementing steps using Cucumber, you usually create a helper class that the step implementation delegates to. This helper class can, and often is, a page object.